# Could this be asbestos

Tags: asbestos

House was built in the 1950s. The light blue plastic tiles pictured are glued down with a layer of adhesive (light brown) that covers the span of the walls. The dabs of adhesive (darker brown) were used for paneling that covered the tiles. The tiles break easily as they are a 1/32" thick. Could any of these materials be asbestos?

[image]

Comment: It is possible, but need to have it tested.  The is usually little worry unless you are removing, sanding the stuff.  You leave it alone, it usually leaves you alone.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the only way to know if something contains asbestos is to have it tested by a lab. Looking at a picture online won't cut it.

Comment: Instead of closing it, I would allow the topic starter to accept the answer below. These comments are in a small font and easily overlooked, and asbestos is dangerous stuff so I'd like any random wanderers in to understand that the answer here really is **'get it laboratory tested'**.

Comment: Duplicate (for all practical purposes - with asbestos, it really doesn't matter that much what the suspected item is) with an accepted answer here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/10222/18078

Answer (score 3):

> House was built in the 1950's. Could any of these materials be
> asbestos?

Yes. They could be, the time era is right.

Or not.

You can't tell by looking at them.

A laboratory test is required to tell. Shop around and don't get overcharged for the testing.